# HashSet doesn't guarantee sorting?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class DuplicateCheckMain {
 public static void main(String[] gopal){
  Integer[] args = {6,9,2,55,100,1,6,8,9};
  Integer[] args1 = {3,6,2,3,5};
  Set S = new HashSet();
  DuplicateCheck.checkDuplicate(S,args,new String("HashSet"));
  Set S1 = new HashSet();
  DuplicateCheck.checkDuplicate(S1,args1,new String("HashSet"));

  S = new TreeSet();
  DuplicateCheck.checkDuplicate(S,args,new String("TreeSet"));

  S = new LinkedHashSet();
  DuplicateCheck.checkDuplicate(S,args,new String("LinkedHashSet"));

 }
}

public class DuplicateCheck {

 public static void checkDuplicate(Set S, Integer[] args, String setname){
  for(int i = 0;i<args.length;i++){
   if(!S.add(args[i])){System.out.println("Duplicate element "+args[i]);}
  }
  System.out.println(S +" "+ setname);
 }
}
```

Question: for the HashSet with reference S, the HashSet is not sorted. But for the reference S1, the HashSet is sorted. Why so?

Comment: Please use the code tags. It'll be more readable!

Comment: Could you please provide the output?

Comment: Output:Duplicate element 6
Duplicate element 9
[1, 100, 2, 55, 6, 8, 9] HashSet
Duplicate element 3
[2, 3, 5, 6] HashSet
Duplicate element 6
Duplicate element 9
[1, 2, 6, 8, 9, 55, 100] TreeSet
Duplicate element 6
Duplicate element 9
[6, 9, 2, 55, 100, 1, 8] LinkedHashSet

Comment: You don't need to copy a string literal, it a String already.

Answer (score 7):

`HashSet` is *absolutely* not guaranteed to be sorted. The ordering isn't guaranteed *at all*.

From the documentation of the `iterator()` method:

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this set. The elements are returned in no particular order.

`HashSet` is designed to insert and check for the presence of elements very quickly, by equality. That's all.

If you need sorting, you should use an implementation of `SortedSet`, such as `TreeSet` or `ConcurrentSkipListSet`.

Answer (score 3):

HashSet used a mod to store the number into a bucket entry

In the `args1` array all the number are less then 16 - the default HashSet size. that is why it ends up being sorted.

Comment: if that is the case, then why doesnt it sorts during command line input to main? provided array numbers are less than 16.

Comment: @gopal Please post the "command line input to main" code... as the other answers point out, `HashSet` does **not** guarantee sorting. never. i was just explaining why in the `args1` situation it happened to be sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that beyond not guarantying sorting, `HashSet`s iteration order may change completely if you insert new elements. For instance:

```
public class TestHashSet {
    public static void main(String[] foo) {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        set.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {6,9,2,55,100,1,6,8,9}));
        System.out.println(set);
        set.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {7,3,13,37,66}));
        System.out.println(set);
        set.add(42);
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

Gave me the following output:

```
[1, 100, 2, 55, 6, 8, 9]
[1, 100, 2, 3, 55, 66, 6, 37, 7, 8, 9, 13]
[1, 2, 100, 3, 6, 66, 7, 37, 8, 42, 9, 13, 55]
```

Notice how the insertion of a single element changed completely the order.

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` does not guarantee sorting. To have sorting feature, use `TreeSet` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Set` guarantees "no duplicate elements".

`java.util.SortedSet` guarantees ordering and "no duplicate elements".